# How to select just first row from table in bigquery - to reduce cost

Tags: select, google-bigquery, row

Hi I need to select just one row of each table - it doesn't mater which row - I just need to control a value in column (which is in every row the same),
but limit or first_value go thru whole table. For me is good one random row...
I need to reduce cost for this query.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If we don't limit to use only SQL. [tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list) API helps you to fetch data from a table for free, if you respect the [limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#tabledatalist_requests) for the API.

I'm not aware of an equivalent thing in SQL. You may have to keep a smaller table by the side to scan instead.